# regex match either string in linux "find" command

Tags: regex, linux, find

I'm trying the following to recursively look for files ending in either `.py` or `.py.server`:

```
$ find -name "stub*.py(|\.server)"
```

However this does not work.

I've tried variations like:

```
$ find -name "stub*.(py|py\.server)"
```

They do not work either.

A simple `find -name "*.py"` does work so how come this `regex` does not?

Comment: Try `find -name "stub*.py(\.server)?"`

Comment: Use `-regex` if you want to use regular expression: `find . -regex '.*/stub.*\.\(py\|py\.server\)'`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Say:

```
find . \( -name "*.py" -o -name "*.py.server" \)
```

Saying so would result in file names matching `*.py` and `*.py.server`.

From `man find`:

```
   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

EDIT: If you want to specify a regex, use the `-regex` option:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(py\|py\.server\)"
```

Comment: This works!

Thanks a lot and +1, but why don't regular expressions work?

Comment: I can only accept it in 6 minutes... :)

I'm still curious as to regular expressions

Comment: @ReutSharabani You can specify regex in an alternate form.  See edit.

Comment: It would a good idea to tell people that they need to put -o expressions in parentheses in case other options follow: `find . '(' -name this -o -name that ')' -user xy -exec ...`

Comment: @Ingo Thanks.  Using parenthesis is something that I also recommend, happened to omit in this case.  More so because upon saying `find . -type f -name "foo*" -o -name "bar*"` would match directories starting with `bar` unless parens are specified!

Comment: Why do you have to escape the round brackets and the pipe sign in the regex? They're used in their regex function, aren't they?

Comment: @gozzilli I'm wondering the same thing, and yet it doesn't seem to work on my machine without them!

Answer (score 7):

Find can take a regular expression pattern:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[.]py([.]server)?$' -print
```

Options:

> -regex pattern
>
> File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path,  not  a  search. For  example,  to  match  a  file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression `.*bar.` or
> `.*b.*3`, but not `f.*r3`.  The regular expressions  understood  by  find  are  by  default  Emacs
> Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.
>
> -print True;

> print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a newline.   If you are piping
> the output of find into another program and there is the faintest possibility that the files which
> you  are  searching  for  might  contain  a  newline, then you should seriously consider using the
> -print0 option instead of -print.  See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES section  for  information  about  how
> unusual characters in filenames are handled.
>
> -regextype type
>
> Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later  on
> the  command line.  Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-
> basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.

A clearer [description](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20-regextype%20posix-extended%20-regex%20%27.*%5B.%5Dpy%28%5B.%5Dserver%29?$%27%20-print) or the options. Don't forgot all the information can be found by reading `man find` or `info find`.

Comment: is this just for the GNU find? Or for BSD as well?

Comment: @baxx It's only for GNU `find`. BSD's version defaults to POSIX "basic" regex syntax (which is *extremely* basic); you can change it to POSIX "extended" regex syntax with the `-E` option, but it's a command option so it goes before the directory to search (i.e. `find -E . -regex '.*[.]py([.]server)?$'`), not after it like the GNU version's `-regextype` primary.

Answer (score 6):

find `-name` does not use regexp, here's an extract from the man page on Ubuntu 12.04

```
-name pattern
              Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
              removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   The metacharacters
              (`*', `?', and `[]') match a `.' at the start of the  base  name
              (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CON‐
              FORMANCE below).  To ignore a directory and the files under  it,
              use  -prune; see an example in the description of -path.  Braces
              are not recognised as being special, despite the fact that  some
              shells  including  Bash  imbue  braces with a special meaning in
              shell patterns.  The filename matching is performed with the use
              of  the  fnmatch(3)  library function.   Don't forget to enclose
              the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from  expansion  by
              the shell.
```

So the pattern that `-name` takes is more like a shell glob and not at all like a regexp

If I wanted to find by regexp I'd do something like

```
find . -type f -print | egrep 'stub(\.py|\.server)'
```

Comment: It is plainly wrong to state that *find does not use regexp* (while it is true to say that *the pattern that ``-name`` takes is more like a shell glob*).